# Libraries are not adding into Android Private Libraries folder in Android

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

Have multiple libraries in project . The issue is suddenly my libraries are not adding to "Android private libraries" folder which is essential for using libraries . Please help me out with the issue. Issue is taking place with only single project in workspace , other are working cool.
Pls note: In java build path ---> order and export ---> have checked private libraries . SO this cant be issue for this problem .
[image]

My present SDK tools configuration
[image]

```
Console message on cleaning:
[2013-08-24 18:03:33 - Twitter4jSample] Unable to resolve target 'android-7'
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject] Versions found are:
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject] Path: D:\Project BackUps\project2 gen\dev\facebookSDK\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject]   Length: 484258
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject]   SHA-1: bd6479f5dd592790607e0504e66e0f31c2b4d308
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject] Path: D:\Project BackUps\project2 gen\dev\projectAPP\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject]   Length: 556198
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject]   SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject] Versions found are:
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject] Path: D:\Project BackUps\project2 gen\dev\facebookSDK\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject]   Length: 484258
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject]   SHA-1: bd6479f5dd592790607e0504e66e0f31c2b4d308
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject] Path: D:\Project BackUps\project2 gen\dev\projectAPP\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject]   Length: 556198
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject]   SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
[2013-08-24 18:03:34 - myproject] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2013-08-24 18:03:49 - myproject] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-08-24 18:03:49 - myproject] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-08-24 18:03:49 - myproject] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-08-24 18:03:49 - myproject] Versions found are:
[2013-08-24 18:03:49 - myproject] Path: D:\Project BackUps\project2 gen\dev\facebookSDK\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-08-24 18:03:49 - myproject]   Length: 484258
[2013-08-24 18:03:49 - myproject]   SHA-1: bd6479f5dd592790607e0504e66e0f31c2b4d308
[2013-08-24 18:03:49 - myproject] Path: D:\Project BackUps\project2 gen\dev\projectAPP\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-08-24 18:03:49 - myproject]   Length: 556198
[2013-08-24 18:03:49 - myproject]   SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
[2013-08-24 18:03:49 - myproject] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2013-08-24 18:04:07 - myproject] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-08-24 18:04:07 - myproject] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-08-24 18:04:07 - myproject] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-08-24 18:04:07 - myproject] Versions found are:
[2013-08-24 18:04:07 - myproject] Path: D:\Project BackUps\project2 gen\dev\facebookSDK\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-08-24 18:04:07 - myproject]   Length: 484258
[2013-08-24 18:04:07 - myproject]   SHA-1: bd6479f5dd592790607e0504e66e0f31c2b4d308
[2013-08-24 18:04:07 - myproject] Path: D:\Project BackUps\project2 gen\dev\projectAPP\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-08-24 18:04:07 - myproject]   Length: 556198
[2013-08-24 18:04:07 - myproject]   SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
[2013-08-24 18:04:07 - myproject] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2013-08-24 18:04:17 - myproject] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-08-24 18:04:17 - myproject] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-08-24 18:04:17 - myproject] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-08-24 18:04:17 - myproject] Versions found are:
[2013-08-24 18:04:17 - myproject] Path: D:\Project BackUps\project2 gen\dev\facebookSDK\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-08-24 18:04:17 - myproject]   Length: 484258
[2013-08-24 18:04:17 - myproject]   SHA-1: bd6479f5dd592790607e0504e66e0f31c2b4d308
[2013-08-24 18:04:17 - myproject] Path: D:\Project BackUps\project2 gen\dev\projectAPP\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-08-24 18:04:17 - myproject]   Length: 556198
[2013-08-24 18:04:17 - myproject]   SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
[2013-08-24 18:04:17 - myproject] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Comment: Just restart your eclipse and see.

Comment: if you have an error after an `eclipse -> project -> clean` in your console please paste it.

Comment: restarting didnt solved . @mansoulx have edited question have a look

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have different `support library added` into your projet:

```
Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list, but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
```

That means that you must have the same version of that jar in your project and all the libraries you are using.

To solve it you can remove the `android-support-v4.jar` that is in your projet. And after you can chose one of that jar somewhere in your computer (you can chose the one provided by the sdk) and after you paste it everywhere you have to include it. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that i was using facebook SDK which also needs android support 4 jar and in the main project also i had added support 4 jar in my project . SO there was a conflict . 
Solution : remove support jar from your main project 
Thanks for ur time

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me as well, and I finally noticed in the background I had the SDK Manager open, waiting for my proxy credentials to be entered.  Once I closed down the SDK Manager and restarted Eclipse, the Android Private Libraries showed back up.